# What was this game with a "Conan" style character on Atari ST?

Tags: identify-this-game, atari-st

This is about a 2D (third person) game I remember seeing being played on an Atari ST computer.

In the game the player controls a "Conan" style character (holding a sword, if I remember correctly). In the scene I remember seeing, the character climbed down a ladder on what looked like a cave man style cliff face and attacked some cave-men(?) with the sword.

In the scene that I saw, the player could then choose to climb back up or further down on another ladder, to take on other cave men.

What game might this have been?

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing. Please read the [tour]. This is a good question - thanks for providing enough information to make an accurate identification of the game.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may be referring to [Barbarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarian_(1987_video_game)) and Barbarian II from game developer [Psygnosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psygnosis).

Comment: yes, thank you @BrianH. Looking at [this image](http://www.atarimania.com/game-atari-st-barbarian_s7503.html) it seems to be it.

Comment: Are you sure that Barbarian was developed by Psygnosis?  I always thought it was developed and published by Palace Software.

Comment: Never mind.  I was thinking of a different [Barbarian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbarian:_The_Ultimate_Warrior) game, also released in 1987.

Comment: There were 2 barbarians: a platformer from paygnosis and a fighting game, when head cutting, from palace software

Comment: Could also be Rygar

Answer (score 4):

I think the game described is Rastan, a coin-op from Taito, later converted to several formats by Ocean Software, as is the case at hand.

[Rastan description in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rastan_(video_game))

Kind regards.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Please read the [tour]. This game is not the game that the question asker was looking for - they have already marked an existing answer with the green tick which, for [tag:identify-this-game] questions, means that the game is the right one. _However_, this might still help other people who come across this question looking for that game.

Comment: It would improve your answer if you added how this matches the question. One way of doing this is copying a phrase from the question with "`> `" at the beginning, leaving a blank line, then describing that part of the game. If you need any help with anything (e.g. formatting, site rules etc.), feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Although already answered, there was a whole genre of these games in the late 80s. Another was [Savage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savage_(video_game)) by Probe Software for Firebird. The game is mostly forgettable, but it did have unbelievably good (for the time, and if you liked hokey takes on *The Art of Noise*) music by Kevin Collier: [Savage (Amiga) - Level 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8NDwMqaGWA)

Comment: ISTR when I was reviewing for magazines, *Savage* came with a whole extra disk just for the music.

Answer (score 2):

It could have been Targhan, from Silmarils, in a more aventurous style.